# How to find least and maximum dates from two different dates?

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I have month in an integer variable `int month =DateTime.Now.Month;` and I have Two dates in database they are `'11/01/2014'`and `'11/30/2014'` . Now I want to bring least and grater days in a string. how can I achieve it.`(in database I have Fromdate('11/01/2014') and Todate('11/30/2014')fields)`? I am new in this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `Min` and `Max` functions you can use to find this.  The best way to use these is to ensure that you are first storing the date as a `date` or `datetime` value (or similar), as casting from one type to another can be an expensive operation.

Sample:

```
Select Min( MyDateColumn) as "MinDate", Max(MyDateColumn) as "MaxDate"
    From MyTable;
```

If they are not stored as a form of date value, you will have to cast the value to a date.  If it is stored as a `varchar` or `char`, for example, you will need to do this. If you don't, the min and max will be calculated based on the ascii values of characters, not on the actual dates.

Sample (avoid, if possible):

```
Select Min( CAST(MyDateColumn as date) ) as "MinDate", 
       Max( CAST(MyDateColumn as date) ) as "MaxDate"
    From MyTable;
```